# MSIntue SDK iOS app not redirecting after login and enrollment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, intunemam

I have updated Intune SDK to 17.4.2.
Building with Xcode 14.3.
MAC OS Ventura 13.3.1 (a)
Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2578
Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.5

We use the default Intune Authentication.
When the Intune login button is pressed, the authentication is not completed.
Is there any extra keys that has to be set when using the latest Intune SDK.
We are updating from Intune SDK 14.3.5. Hence is there something we are missing.
We have registered our app in Azure Active directory. But we have not used it anywhere in our application.
Is that affecting the login process.

Tried in various Intune versions after 14.3.5. But unsuccessful.